# Two way binding of NG-STYLE not working in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to show popup after 10 secs. I am resetting variable from another component. When I am running the app it is calling show function correctly.

But in my ng style condition not changing from display none to flex.

I have attached my code here, please refer. Thanks in advance.

Component1.ts

```
import { ReconnectModalComponent } from './shared/components/reconnect-modal/reconnect-modal.component';

@Component({
  providers:[ReconnectModalComponent],
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
})

constructor(private reconnectComp: ReconnectModalComponent ) { 
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.sessionService.isSessionAlive().subscribe((result: any) => {
      try {
        this.reconnectComp.show()
      } catch (ex) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(ex));
      }
    })
}
```

Component2.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'reconnect-modal',
  templateUrl: 'reconnect-modal.component.html',
  styles: [`
    .modal {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .modal-content {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      border-radius: 0;
      padding: 40px;
    }
    .modal-header {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .modal-header,
    .modal-body,
    .modal-footer {
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .modal-body {
      font: 18px/23px "DinProRegular", sans-serif;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .modal-body,
    .modal-footer {
      text-align: center;
    }
  `]
})
export class ReconnectModalComponent {
  @ViewChild('content') modal: ElementRef;
  public visible = true;
  private visibleAnimate = true;

  constructor() {}

  public show(): void {
    this.visible = true;
    setTimeout(() => this.visibleAnimate = true, 100);
  }

  public hide(): void {
    this.visibleAnimate = false;
    setTimeout(() => this.visible = false, 300);
  }

  public onContainerClicked(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if ((<HTMLElement>event.target).classList.contains('modal')) {
      this.hide();
    }
  }

}
```

Componnet.html

```
  <div (click)="onContainerClicked($event)" class="malaii modal fade" tabindex="-1" 
  [ngClass]="{'in': visibleAnimate}"
  [ngStyle]="{
    'display': visible ? 'flex' : 'none', 
    'opacity': visibleAnimate ? 1 : 0,
    'z-index': visible ? 1050 : 0
  }">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    {{visible}}
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <ng-content select=".header"></ng-content>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ng-content select=".body"></ng-content>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <ng-content select=".footer"></ng-content>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where  is ```in``` class in your css ?

Comment: I am facing problem in ngStyle visible .

Comment: your code seems working fine check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckecqi)

Comment: i think your problem is you are not assigning  #content to any element.

Comment: I am updating this variable from other component using using providers

Comment: Hi @fatemefazli  I edited my question Please check now.

Comment: you are call the show method of your component instance and the instance change it's own visible variable, but you can't fine active instance of your component easily, best way is define a shared service and using it change value from another component .

Comment: Ok @fatemefazli Event emitter is it fine?

Comment: yes you can use ```@input``` ```@output``` and event emitters.